# .NET API can't recognize/authorize Azure AD user through authorized client's JWT

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to authorize Azure Active Directory users logged into a NextJS client application (using [msal-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-react)) through my .NET 8 API so they can use `[Authorize]` endpoints. However, upon sending a client JWT to my API, I receive a 401 response and my API logs a `DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement`.

I have registered both applications through Azure's App registrations. In my API registration, I have exposed my API to authorize my client app through a single scope, `access_as_user`. I have confirmed this in my client's registration as a Delegated permission.
[image: Azure AD App registration screen showing the Expose an API page]

[image: API permissions for my API app]

[image: API permissions for my client app]

[image: Showing I'm granting access and ID tokens]

In my .NET API, I'm setting my `AzureAd` configuration in `appsettings.json`

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "qualified.domain.name",
  "TenantId": "API-TENANT-ID",
  "ClientId": "API-CLIENT-ID",
  "Scopes": "access_as_user",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

I then add authentication to my services in my `Program.cs`

```
...
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(config.GetSection("AzureAd"));
...
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
...
```

Finally, I've set up a simple controller with a single `[Authorize]` endpoint.

```
[Controller]
[Route("api")]
public class GeneralController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("get")]
    public Task<IActionResult> Test()
    {
        return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(Ok());
    }
}
```

In my client application, I retrieve my token after a user logs in with Azure AD.

```
const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
...
instance.acquireTokenSilent({
   scopes: [
     "api://API-CLIENT-ID/access_as_user",
   ],
     account: account,
})
```

I'm able to log the token retrieved by the client app succesfully and, when using https://jwt.io/, I can decode the JWT to find the following relevant properties:

```
{
  "aud": "API-CLIENT-ID",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/CLIENT-TENANT-ID/v2.0",
  "azp": "CLIENT-CLIENT-ID",
  "name": "LOGGED-IN-USER-NAME",
  "scp": "access_as_user",
  "tid": "CLIENT-TENANT-ID",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

However, when I include this token in a request's Authorization header to the general endpoint I set up, I receive a 401 response and the following logs from my API:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
```

Comment: Where do you call `UseAuthentication`?

Comment: My bad, forgot to include that as part of my `Program.cs` snippet. Revised.

Comment: `MY-CLIENT-ID` in the config and `API-CLIENT-ID` in the token are identical?

Comment: Yes they are, I've renamed to match the global ID naming convention I used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General speaking, by default, the web API protect by AAD requires a token which `aud` claim value should match the value we defined in the appsettings.json, so that it's a valid token. If we didn't define `Audience` property in appsetting, the default value for it is the `ClientId` in appsetting.

According to your screenshot, you exposed API `api://my_api_client_id/access_as_user` in your `My API` app. And you already added this API permission into `My client`, that should be ok. Therefore, in your client app, you should have configurations for MSAL that all use `My Client`, and `my_api_client_id` should only appear once when you define the scope you used to generate access token. Please make sure that you can obtain the access token, and [decode it](https://jwt.io/) to see the value for `aud` and `scp`. If value of `aud` is `my_api_client_id`, then we don't need to change anything in your web api appsettings.json. If value of `aud` is `api://my_api_client_id`, pls add `Audience` property like below.

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "qualified.domain.name",
  "TenantId": "My-TENANT-ID",
  "ClientId": "backend_aad_app-CLIENT-ID",
  "Scopes": "access_as_user",
  "Audience": "api://clientid_of_the_app_exposed_api_which_should_be_id_of_backend_aad_app"
},
```

Comparing the information you shared above, all codes look good, so that could you pls checking the app ids you used in each place to make sure they didn't mix up? In the mean time, we might use only one app which is the `My API` both in the client and the backend api.

I followed the official sample and had a test in my side, it worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've verified and added screenshots for my set API permissions for both my API and client app registrations. I also added the `Audience` property you suggested to my `AzureAd` config object and set the value to the client's client ID. Unfortunately, I still received the same error. :/

Comment: @Griffin Hi, I double confirmed in my side and updated my post. When we have 2 apps, one for the client and another for the backend api. We require one of them to expose an API, then the exposed API should be added API permission to the client APP. Authentication should use the information related to the client APP, and the backend API should use client id of the backend app. If the api is exposed by the backend app, then we don't need to set `Audience` in webapi project, otherwise we need to define it, the value depends on the access token `aud` claim.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as accepted since it's well researched and future Overflow users may find this helpful in diagnosing their AD issues. In actuality, my issue was I forgot to wrap my Authorization Bearer object in a `headers` object (`fetch("https://localhost:5000/api/get", { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token}})` vs `fetch("https://localhost:5000/api/get", {Authorization: "Bearer " + token })`). Great use of two days worth of diagnosing 

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind reply and your update on this question :D